# ajuda com identação que está gerando erro no python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, loop, python-2.7

Estou fazendo um webcrawler estou tendo o seguinte problema. Tive que fazer um programa a parte para imprimir quantos candidatos passaram em cada curso. Só que a última linha não está sendo executada, sendo que ela que iria fazer o vetor de nomes passar para o proximo curso da lista. A linha que não está sendo executada é a última que está escrito :   posicao = posicao +1
 O código é este

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests  
import string
import re
import urllib 
cursos = [
'ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO A',
'ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO B',  
'ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO D',
'ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO E',
'ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO A',
'ADMINISTRAÇÃO - JUIZ DE FORA - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO B'

]

r = requests.get('http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=05GV&id_grupo=72')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
vetor = [] 
posicao =1
for node in soup.findAll("td"):
  candidato =node.get_text("td")
  vetor.append(candidato)
  contador = 0

  for s in vetor:
   contador = contador +1
  contador = int(contador/5)
  contador = 5
  contador2 = 0
  contador2 = int(contador2)
  print(contador)
  while contador2<=contador:
   print(cursos[posicao])
  posicao = posicao +1
```

Comment: A minha resposta à tua pergunta anterior não te ajudou? perguntei-te se ias fazer isto. Não precisas usar urllib se usas requests

Comment: Sim ajudou ue, até lhe dei melhor answer  Oo

Comment: explica-me melhor o que pretendes que o programa faça sff

Comment: Eu preciso imprimir quantos candidatos estão listados em cada curso. Neste caso eu acho que a lógica está certa. O problema é última linha que não está sendo executada. Ela deveria ser executada assim que o "while"  termina,  e essa lista de  " cursos" está reduzida pois são muitos.  Se voce abrir essa url que está no request vai entender um pouco melhor o que estou a dizer. voce vera que tem o curso e quantos candidatos estão listados lá.

Comment: mas queres só saber quantos candidatos há? 150 neste caso? Só não percebo porquê tanto código para fazer isso, na minha outra resposta faz isso, é só trocar o url

Comment: não é só saber quantos há. eu preciso imprimir cada curso tantas vezes tiverem candidados listados nele. POr exemplo nesse eu preciso imprimir 150 vezes o nome do curso, o que seria feito caminhando neste vetor que eu chamei de cursos, só que a variavel posição não está sendo alterada no fim da impressão, para poder passar para o próximo curso

Comment: Miguel , realmente eu estava voando hard. Sua answer da outra pergunta já salvo tudo , Very thanks

Comment: De nada nada ainda bem que resolveu

Answer (score 1):

A posição não está sendo incrementada no laço do `while`

```
while contador2 <= contador:
    print(cursos[posicao])
    posicao = posicao +1
```

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar eu te sugiro que siga o guia de estilo pep8 (https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo) que recomenda 4 espaços para a indentação.

Especificamente sobre o seu problema: Altere o seu bloco While (ultimo bloco antes da linha que vc menciona) para o seguinte:

```
while contador2<=contador:
    print ('contador: ', contador, 'contador2: ' contador2)
```

E vc vai ver que na verdade vc esta entrando em um loop infinito, pois a variável "contador" terá sempre o valor de 5 e a variável "contador2" o valor 0 (zero).

Corrija esse while e a linha que incrementa a posicao será atingida.

Novamente: Siga a convenção de estilo, indentação com 4 espaços; SEMPRE.